# Codeigniter library not working

Tags: codeigniter

Am working on codeigniter custom library. I have attached library function and controller function along with my post.

My code

**Controller:-**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('pagination_library');
}

function index(){
   $this->pagination_library->orders();
}
```

**Pagination_library:**

```
class Pagination_library {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('pagination_model');
    $this->CI->load->library('pagination');
  }

  public function orders(){
  }

}
```

Am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no
>   parent

Comment: remove the first line of struct method, cause this class don't have a super class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
class Pagination_library { 

function __construct() 
  {
    // parent::__construct();
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('pagination_model');
    $this->CI->load->library('pagination');
  }
  public function orders()
  {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not extending this class from any other class . so parent:: will not work. try this. and follow this tutorial if you still face any problem while creating library [Link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

```
   public function orders()
  {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('pagination_model');
    $this->CI->load->library('pagination');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function pager($total,$segment=3,$perpage=PP){

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    if($segment==3){
        $config['base_url'] = base_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2));
    }elseif($segment == 4){
        $config['base_url'] = base_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3));
    }elseif($segment==5){
        $config['base_url'] = base_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3).'/'.$this->uri->segment(4));
    }elseif($segment==2){
        $config['base_url'] = base_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/');
    }
    $config['uri_segment'] = $segment;

    $config['total_rows'] = $total;
    $config['per_page'] = $perpage;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

    $config['first_link'] = '&laquo;';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['last_link'] = '&raquo;';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['next_link'] = '&rarr;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_link'] = '&larr;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    return $this->pagination->create_links();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In libraries when making them you do not need the

```
parent::__construct();
```

Change this

```
class Pagination_library {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('pagination_model');
    $this->CI->load->library('pagination');
  }

  public function orders(){
  }

}
```

Remove parent::__construct();

To This

```
class Pagination_library {

  function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->model('pagination_model');
    $this->CI->load->library('pagination');
  }

  public function orders(){
  }

}
```